# Sourceforge daily builds

Tags: java, ant, build, sourceforge, dailybuilds

I currently mantain an open-source project hosted in SourceForge.
My project is written in Java using ANT build scripts. (Ant has a few extensions installed, but let's ignore that for now.)

Unfortunately, there seems to be no easy way to automatically generate daily builds. Is there any workaround I can use. Here is what I want:

1. It should *always* use the most recent SVN version.
2. It should build it.
3. It should publish it online. If it fails, it should publish the error report.
4. These tasks should be done **automatically**.

How can I do this? How can I emulate automatic daily builds of a project hosted in SourceForge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem what you need is a Continuous Integration tool. It will pool the SCM for you, start a build and publish/store the error report in case of failure.

My favorite one is Hudson:

https://hudson.dev.java.net/

Comment: I'm trying to make it work.
Once I get it to work, I'll have to find out a way to automatically start the tasks.

Comment: When you create a task you can configure it to pool SCM so it will build whenever there are changes.

Comment: First, I need to figure out how to make the Ant work from the command line.
I'll definitively look into SCM, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think SF has a hook for emails on commits.

http://apps.sourceforge.net/trac/sitedocs/wiki/Subversion
http://apps.sourceforge.net/trac/sitedocs/wiki/Subversion%20hook%20scripts#svnnotify

I would imagine that you could trigger off of that.

Alternatively a process that checks the latest revision every hour (or whatever period you want) using (svn up) would be enough to trigger a build? (keep a record of the last known built revision and if the current revision if different, then trigger a build)

I am not familiar with them, but I suspect third party tools (CI/Continuous integration) to do builds have a way of determining a build trigger event from SVN.